# Java EE project on Intellij Community

Tags: java-ee-8

I have searched but not found an exact answer for my question even though I tried all the possibilities. Is it possible to create a Java EE project with Intellij Community edition?
I don't see Java enterprise option.

Answer (score 0):

Please view the [IDEA version comparsion](https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=idea-ce)

[image]

The Community does not support Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to switch to **Ultimate** version with special [offers](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/#discounts). For example if you are student you can ask for free **Ultimate** account.

But in general community edition does not support Java EE project creation.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698847/how-to-use-java-ee-intellij-idea-community-edition) article for more information.